# Cannot log into Stack Overflow after using another account

Tags: support, login

I was testing an alternate account for Stack Overflow (by creating it and logging in), and now I am unable to log back into Stack Overflow using my original credentials.

When I click on the Stack Exchange login link, it automatically sends me in as my test/alternate account.

---

**Edit:**
2013-03-20 - I tried deleting cookies related to stackoverflow.com and stackexchange.com, but I am still getting logged in as the 'test' user account.

This really feels like a bug, as there is never an opportunity for a user to specify a user account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout and click logout

Then go here: https://openid.stackexchange.com/user and click logout

Then log back in.

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter such problem, I usually clear web browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Empty the cache of your browser would work.